# Create foreignkey object instances on parent create - Django

Tags: python, django

**models.py**

```
class Req(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    # fileup is a csv of 6 digit barcodes
    fileup = models.FileField(upload_to='uploads/')

class ReqBarcodes(models.Model):
    barcode = models.CharField(max_length=6)
    req = models.ForeignKey(Req, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

When the user uploads their csv, I would like to create ReqBarcodes instances for all barcodes contained in that csv file, analagous to on_delete CASCADE, but something like on_create CASCADE. My guess would be that I need to define a custom **init** method inside the Req model class. If so, can I perform csv validation inside that as well? Will either class instance be created if the validation fails? I would prefer not to have the classes created, and I will redirect the user to try again.

I am also using a generic create view at this point. Can I modify this view, or is it necessary to write a completely custom view?

**views.py**

```
class RequestCreate(CreateView):
    model = Request
    fields = ['name', 'upload']
    success_url = reverse_lazy('requests:index')
```

Comment: You could override the save method of `Req` to create `ReqBarcode` objects and link them to `Req`. This wouldn't require modifying your generic create view.

Comment: And how is django supposed to know what data should go into the related model/